# How can i skip each 9 items when adding to a List?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```c#
public void ImagesLinks()
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach(string c in DatesAndTimes)
    {
        if (count == 9)
        {
            count = 0;
        }
        string imageUrl = firstUrlPart + countriescodes[count] + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[count] + thirdUrlPart + "true";
        imagesUrls.Add(imageUrl);
        count++;
    }
}
```

The List DatesAndTimes is in this format: Each line is item in the List.

```
201612281150201612281150
201612281150201612281151
201612281150201612281152
201612281150201612281153
201612281150201612281154
201612281150201612281155
201612281150201612281156
201612281150201612281157
201612281150201612281158
201612281150201612281159
Europe
201612281150201612281150
201612281150201612281151
201612281150201612281152
201612281150201612281153
201612281150201612281154
201612281150201612281155
201612281150201612281156
201612281150201612281157
201612281150201612281158
201612281150201612281159
Turkey
```

Every 10 items there is a name.
I want to skip the name when i build the links.
So i count to 9 each time ( count 10 times from 0 to 9 ) then i reset the counter to 0 and i also want to skip the name for example Europe then count to 10 again and skip Turkey and so on.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just filter out the strings which contain letters?

Comment: You use `count` to index two different arrays `countriescodes` and `DatesAndTimes`. It would seem that either you have a big array that has 9 time each country or you should be getting IndexOutOfRange exception. Also you never use `c`. I would totally modify this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `continue` in the if statement. It will skip the line after and resume the `foreach` loop execution.

```
public void ImagesLinks()
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach(string c in DatesAndTimes)
                {
                    if (count == 9)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                        continue;
                    }
                    string imageUrl = firstUrlPart + countriescodes[count] + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[count] + thirdUrlPart + "true";
                    imagesUrls.Add(imageUrl);
                    count++;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `(count % 9 == 0)`, this way you don't have to reset the counter:

```
public void ImagesLinks()
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach(string c in DatesAndTimes)
    {
        if (count++ % 9 == 0)
            continue;

        string imageUrl = firstUrlPart + countriescodes[count] + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[count] + thirdUrlPart + "true";
        imagesUrls.Add(imageUrl);
    }
}
```